# Show a users answers at the end of a quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a simple quiz and am storing the users answers in a database. I have access to the answers as json, which looks like this:

```
{
    "form":{
        "1":{
            "M1_Q1PRE":{
                "a1":"a1"
            }
        },
        "2":{
            "M1_Q2PRE":{
               "a2":"a2"
            }
        },
        "3":{
            "M1_Q3PRE":{
                "a2":"a2",
                "a4":"a4"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

(question 3 was multi select checkboxes)

I am trying to build a page at the end of the quiz, that will show all the questions, and the chosen answers that the user chose. I want to hard code the final page:

```
<p>Question One</p>
<ol type="a">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1_Q1PRE" value="a1"> answer a
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1_Q1PRE" value="a2"> answer b
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
<p>Question Two</p>
<ol type="a">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1_Q2PRE" value="a1"> answer a
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="M1_Q2PRE" value="a2"> answer b
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
<p>Question Three</p>
<ol type="a">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="M1_Q3PRE" value="a1"> answer a
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="M1_Q3PRE" value="a2"> answer b
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="M1_Q3PRE" value="a3"> answer c
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="M1_Q3PRE" value="a4"> answer d
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

What I am trying to do is highlight/check the answers that the user chose using the json result. I can't edit the json, as the backend was built for something else and I am trying to repurpose it for this quiz. Does anyone know of a way to parse through the json and use it to automatically populate the users answers?

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtca9kax/

Thanks, 
S

## EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/mtca9kax/2/

I've updated my fiddle to include a more accurate json response. There are also questions that have multiple answers (see Q2... lots of T/F). I've got it working, but don't know how to loop over the data.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Where's your Javascript fetching the JSON? side note, it's nasty the answers would be passed in objects like that...

Comment: I've updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mtca9kax/2/ with what I have been trying. It's a little more complicated now. The js grabbing the results is coming from a 'widget' that was created by someone else. I don't have access to changing the json. Wish I did.

Comment: The input name on your json is different from the name on your input. At least for question 3. `M1_Q3aPRE ~= M1_Q3PRE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

You have to loop into your json response, and use the values to select the proper answer.

```
$.each(results.form, function (ind, val) {
    $.each(val, function (inde, value) {
        $.each(value, function (index, radio) {
            //console.log(radio);
            $('input[name="'+ inde +'"][value="'+ radio +'"]').prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mtca9kax/3/).

Comment: That worked beautifully. I have been working on it all morning, and actually figured out a MUCH uglier way to do it. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should do loop upon JSON object and map key M1_Q1PRE (for example) on the element with same name.
If you don't like clear javascript use jQuery library or same
(jQuery.each -- for loop, jQuery(element).val() -- for set value to the element).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the json/js-object and set the checked property for the users answers:

```
var answers = JSON.parse(your_json);
for(var i in answers) {
 var answer = answers[i];
 $('ol:eq(+'parseInt(i)+)' input[value="'+answer['M1_Q'+i+'PRE']+'"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

As you see, the json format has room for optimization for this purpose ;-)

Oh, there are actually the answers ids as key and values inside the M1_Q... objects - that needs to be solved to make the answer above work... the general idea should be visible, however.

(Better change the json to a more appropriate format.)